# Accessing Button Target Throwing Error

Tags: uikit, swift2

With the code below I get an error when I press the button. I'm not sure why.The error is unrecognized selector sent to instance and terminates with "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException." Any help sure is appreciated.
Thanks

```
class WordSearchWindow: UIViewController {

let boardsize = 10

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    buttonGridder()
}

func buttonGridder() {
    for x in 0..<self.boardsize {
        for y in 0..<self.boardsize{
            let sizer = ButtonGrid.frame.width
            let buttonSize:CGFloat = sizer / CGFloat(self.boardsize)
            let letterButton = WordButton(column: x, row: y, buttonSize: buttonSize, buttonMargin: 0)
            letterButton.addTarget(self, action: "letterFirst", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            letterButton.addTarget(self, action: "letterSecond", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            self.ButtonGrid.addSubview(letterButton)
        }
    }
}

func letterFirst(sender: WordButton) {
    print("hello1")
}

func letterSecond(sender: WordButton) {
    print("hello2")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
letterButton.addTarget(self, action: "letterFirst:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
letterButton.addTarget(self, action: "letterSecond:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Add `:` in the action

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks